# If the particles show uncertainity ,then why the body made of particles cant show that?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

What i want to know is that if the properties of the quantumn nature reduses if the particles combine?
Or were we missing any fundamental relation to particle or boby made up of particles?

Answer (score 1):

T[his is the Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) relation:

[image: hup]

It reduces the uncertainty within a "volume" of momentum and space. For large bodies, larger than nanometer dimensions, this is a trivial condition to fulfill because their mass ensures that they always fulfill it.

[h_bar is such a small number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) that this is inevitable, and can be considered zero in the everyday dimensions. $1.055*10^{-34}$ joule-second